# When do I need to reinitialize a jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

On page load I store a reference to a field:

```
var firstNameField = $('input[name=firstName]');
```

Are there any cases where that reference would become "stale" meaning attributes or properties of that input element in the `DOM` could change and the `jQuery` element referring to it could no longer carry the correct values?

In other words, in what cases do I need to re-initialize a `jQuery` object in relation to the underlying `DOM` element changing?

Comment: When you don't know this kind of things, the best is to experiment. Try it. Try to get the attributes, change them, get them again, see if you obtain the result you want. You will learn and understand more if you try yourself.

Comment: I agree. I have tried it in the console. The purpose of the question is to find out if there are any edge cases I have not thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any cases where that reference would become "stale" meaning attributes or properties of that input element in the DOM could change and the jQuery element referring to it could no longer carry the correct values?

That specific thing won't happen, no. jQuery just contains a set of maching elements. Those are the actual elements, so if their state changes (for instance, an attribute is changed, etc.), when you go to get that piece of state information from your jQuery set, it will go to the actual DOM element, and thus get current information. For instance:

```js
const d = $("#target");
console.log("before", d.attr("data-example")); // undefined
// Change it without using jQuery
document.getElementById("target").setAttribute("data-example", "updated");
console.log("after ", d.attr("data-example")); // "updated"
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What could happen, but is more rare, is that the element could be **replaced** with a different element. In that case, jQuery will have a reference to the *old* element, not the new one:

```js
const s = $("#wrapper span");
console.log("before", s.text()); // "This is the initial span"
// Completely replace that span with a different element
$("#wrapper").html("<span>This is the new span</span>");
// The jQuery set is still referring to the old span element
console.log("before", s.text()); // "This is the initial span"
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <span>This is the initial span</span>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That's not jQuery-specific, it's true if you're just working with the element directly as well:

```js
const s = document.querySelector("#wrapper span");
console.log("before", s.textContent); // "This is the initial span"
// Completely replace that span with a different element
document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = "<span>This is the new span</span>";
// `s` is still referring to the old span element
console.log("before", s.textContent); // "This is the initial span"
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <span>This is the initial span</span>
</div>
```

(IE had some weird behavior in this regard in that it would go through the old elements wiping out their text, but that was *seriously* non-standard and IE is increasingly obsolete.)

The DOM does offer some *live* collections where as long as you go back to the collection for the element, you'll get the new one:

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
const col = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("span"); // Live collection
console.log("before", col[0].textContent); // "This is the initial span"
// Completely replace that span with a different element
wrapper.innerHTML = "<span>This is the new span</span>";
// `col`'s contents are updated dynamically when the DOM changes
console.log("before", col[0].textContent); // "This is the new span"
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <span>This is the initial span</span>
</div>
```

The collection (`NodeList`) you get from `querySelectorAll` is a snapshot, most others are live collections, such as the ones from `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName`, or the `children` or `childNodes` properties of elements, etc.

Comment: Yes! I think that was the case I was trying to recall! We had a jQuery reference to a DOM element and then we went in and replaced part of the page where this DOM element resided. The reference became obsolete but the actual class selector we used was the same for the old element and the new element so later in the code we assumed the reference was still accurate though it wasn't.Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery will hold a reference to the actual `HTMLElement`. As long as this element is in the DOM it will be valid. If you somehow remove the element (or the element was inserted efter you did `var firstNameField = $('input[name=firstName]');` eg because of Ajax) you will need to "reinitialize".

Of course you could do stupid stuff like `firstNameField[0] = null` and overwrite the reference to the element.